# What about the Model in Large ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

I've been doing some research on using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework together for a fairly large project.
Most examples separate the .edmx file from the MVC project by moving it to a new DAL project. In this project you would also find repositories and interfaces.

While this approach makes perfect sense to me, there's one thing I can't seem to figure out: what about the Models in MVC? In most examples the Controllers address the repository interfaces from the DAL project directly, so the MVC Models are no longer used? Or is it a good idea to keep using them, but map them in the Controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 types of models:

- domain models
- view models

The domain models represent your domain entities. They could be the autogenerated EF classes from your database or coming from somewhere else such as proxies generated from a WCF service that you are consuming. Those should live in your domain layer.

View models on the other hand go in the `Models` folder in the ASP.NET MVC project. Those are specific classes that you define for each view. The controller actions will query your DAL layer to fetch one or more domain models and instantiate a view model which you have specifically defined for the given view that you want to render from this controller. So a view model could hold information from multiple domain models (just because in the given view you need all this information). Then the controller passes the view model to the view for displaying.

Comment: So I would have to do some sort of mapping between the both? In the controller?

Comment: Yes, personally I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to do this mapping. You could separate your mapping definitions in separate files called profiles to avoid cluttering your controllers with mapping logic. It slims them down. In the controller all you need is to use the `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` method that AutoMapper provides.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer! Just one more question: what would be the best place for any Business Logic?

Comment: Depends how complex and reusable you want this logic to be: if you want it to be reusable you would define it in a separate class library from the ASP.NET MVC application. Otherwise you could keep it in the MVC application but make sure you put it in separate folders.